# External phpMyAdmin not showing my database in hostinger

Tags: phpmyadmin

Recently i created free website in hostinger.in . In that i created one Mysql Database. i am able to manage that database using phpmyadmin provided by hostinger. Later i uploaded another phpmyadmin(3.5) to my root folder and tried to access it as www.mydomain.com/phpMyAdmin/index.php and able to login using same login credentials that i got at the time of database creation, but it is not listing any databases after login. is there any exact method to access the database using third party phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 0):

Log in to each phpMyAdmin instance and compare not only username but the host from which you're connecting. This is listed together as the "User" under the "Database server" section on the main page, for instance `root@localhost`. The reason to compare them is that it sounds like one of your instances (the new one you've installed yourself) is probably connecting as a different host than the one provided by your host. Provided that the database and webservers are on the same machine, this likley corresponds to the difference in connecting via socket connections or TCP networking, for which there's a configuration option `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';` or `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'socket';`. Socket would appear as a connection `@localhost` and TCP as `@127.0.0.1`.

Another possibility is that the host-provided version is running on a different server than yours, in which case you might need to tweak your database permissions, but the previous explanation is much more likely.